# update bases on sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this table `Test` as `Id, SomeValue, SomeText` contains about a mill records, I altered the table to

```
ALTER TABLE Test
ADD ComputedColFloat FLOAT
```

all are set to `null`, fine! what I want is that for each row, the value of ComputedColFloat should be set to sum of values in column `SomeValue` upto that row. (The values in `SomeValue` are computed using `RAND()`!)

Say, if before adding the column, first five rows are

```
Id    SomeValue    SomeText
1     .91          text
2     .34          text
3     .52          text
4     .11          text
5     .68          text
```

what I want is to write a query that would update the table and set the added column to reflect the values as

```
Id    SomeValue    SomeText    ComputedColFloat
1     .91          text        .91   // .91
2     .34          text        1.25  // .91 + .34
3     .52          text        1.77  // .91 + .34 + .52
4     .11          text        1.88  // .91 + .34 + .52 + .11
5     .68          text        2.56  // .91 + .34 + .52 + .11 + .68
```

I am using sql server 2008, and would prefer to do this from SSMS not from visual studio by C# or anything! (In C# in VS, I could loop, find the sum and then write a query that would update the records, but that's not what I need, I need to do it from SSMS)
Also, if there are more than 1 way to do this, I would like to know what would be best performance wise, as I have about a mill records, I don't wanna wait up forever! :(

Comment: so, the first value is the result from a Rand() and the rest are the sum of the previous rows?

Comment: @ElVieejo
well all entries in column SomeValue are Rand(), its the column added later `ComputedColFloat` that contains the sum. Actually, I am preparing this for response to answer for my previous question, it was migrated to dba.se, if you wanna check here's the link http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/computed-columns-index-clustered-index-and-covering-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create cursor for your table and update each row.

```
        DECLARE CUR_TEST CURSOR LOCAL For Select ID,SomeValue From test ORDER BY ID ASC
        DECLARE @TOTALSUM FLOAT
                    DECLARE @ID INT
        DECLARE @SOMEMVALUE FLOAT
        OPEN CUR_LOCAL
        SET @TOTALSUM=0
        SET @SOMEVALUE=0
        FETCH CUR_LOCAL INTO @ID,@SOMEVALUE
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @TOTALSUM=@TOTALSUM + @SOMEVALUE
            Update TEST SET ComputedColFloat =@TOTALSUM Where ID=@ID
            FETCH CUR_LOCAL INTO @ID,@SOMEVALUE
        END
        CLOSE CUR_LOCAL
        DEALLOCATE CUR_LOCAL
```

Before executing take a copy of your table to verify

Comment: How would I do that? Can you elaborate with example?

Answer (score 1):

this is a better option than a cursor:

first, set the first value in the first row:

```
update Test set ComputedColFloat = [text] where id = 1
```

then, you just update each row considering the previous row

```
update t2 set ComputedColFloat = [text] + (select ComputedColFloat from Test  where id = t2.id-1 ) from Test t2  where t2.id > 1
```

Comment: okay, but it would only run once and will only update the first record it founds, that is, the record number two, for all updates, we have to loop using while or something for it to process all records!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it turns out to be a really, or I should say the worst way to do this! I tried running this query (both with index on table and without, there was negligible difference) and in both ways, it took about 1 minute to update a single record. I had to cancel the query after about 7-8 minutes knowning that at this rate it would take about a million minutes to update all records :(

Comment: really ? that's weird.. It's a simply update, it's impossible that the first update took more than 1 second..
you have to use it like this, you don't have to loop in a while! Running the second line once it will update every row.
Also, if you don't have continuos Id (if exists Id 1, Id 3, but no Id 2) you have to modify this query a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
declare @sumUptoThatRow float,@query varchar(2000),@Id int,@ComputedColFloat float,@updateQuery nvarchar(max)

set @query = 'declare dbcursor cursor for select Id,ComputedColFloat  from test order by id '

set @sumUptoThatRow = 0.00

exec (@query)

open dbcursor

fetch next from dbcursor into @Id,@ComputedColFloat

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

begin

set @sumUptoThatRow = @sumUptoThatRow + @ComputedColFloat

--Update 
set @updateQuery = 'Update test set ComputedColFloat = ' + sumUptoThatRow + '  where Id = ' + @Id

exec (@updateQuery)

fetch next from dbcursor into @Id,@ComputedColFloat

end

close dbcursor

deallocate dbcursor
```